# Facebook Insights Tab View metric not updating

Tags: tabs, facebook-insights

I currently pull Facebook Insight reports every 3-4 days on my page, however, recently I have noticed that the stats on the "Tab Views" metric have not been changing. Has Facebook undergone any changes in the past week (I had issues getting onto Insights on Thursday)? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I know facebook has many problems last days. My and my friend's comments didn't posted even after we got notifications about it, and unfortunately maybe facebook insights also has problems.

So what I'm saying is - wait...

Answer (score 0):

I have pulled down my Insights exports for the month of January, to have some metrics missing multiple rows of data.  The numbers are always a little off in the Excel export from the numbers I can see on the brand page...I'm hoping with the IPO it gets more reliable